# DFS: Finding the path to a node using depth first search (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search

I have a tree. All nodes in this tree have some true/false value, an element, and parent/children pointers. One element in this tree has the true/false value set to true. I want to find a path (the sequence of elements) from the root to this unique node. So if my tree looked like this:

```
     A
    / \
   B   C
  /     \
 D       E
        / \
       F   G
          / \
         H   I
```

And the special node was H, my algorithm would return the string "ACEGH". I've implemented this using a DFS. However, my current algorithm is adding the elements of the nodes from the incorrect paths. So my current algorithm would return: "ABDCEFGHI".

```
private String dfs(Node node, String path) {

    if(node.special){
        return key;
    }

    for(Node n: node.children){
        if(n != null){
            path = path + n.element;
            dfs(n, path);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *remove* `n.element` from the path if `dfs` returns `null` (interpreting that to mean that the solution path had not been found).  You should also stop checking for children once `dfs` returns non-null.

For this to work, `dfs` should return non-null once it has found a path, regardless of what level it is at.